# Image Uploading

Tags: javascript

i want to upload an image from the client's system, through javascript and store that image on the client side (local storage) not at the server side..and before uploading that image i want to preview that image also...any help will be awesome...
Regards: Zain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with pure javascript, you need server-side script there. Also what you are mentioning is security threat to the clients' machine - not possible either.

Comment: Is there no way to implement?

Comment: there is the website name http://mugtug.com/darkroom/ this is implementing this...

Comment: @user: Also you will never get some hacky-way answers here :)